# Passing value along with MySQL retrieved value as hidden value in JavaScript to AJAX function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, jquery

I have doubt in php, ajax form.. 
let me explain the expected scenario...

1. I have update the quantity of the product in the shopping cart using products id is the Key.
2. I'm using dropdown list, onchange it calls the ajax function and passing the values(ie., is quantity as this.value) along with the products id which is retrieved from mysql DB.
3. In javascript function, it passes two values through ajax and in php, it gets the values and update the quantity for corresponding products_id.
4. On success, it must return the updated value on the form **without reloading the entire page or form**...

I'm stacking with this problem for a week, I cant able to get answer.. Kindly help me..

Let u know how i called the javascript function,

```
<select name="update" onchange="updatequantity(this.value,<?php echo $row['products_id']; ?>)" >
```

But this call function cant send the value to ajax...

Comment: You'd probably have a [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call inside your `updatequantity` function sending those parameters to your PHP and displaying/appending the response text to your document inside its callback, there are thousands of good jquery-ajax guides in the wild (and it's a piece of cake with JQuery).

Answer (score 0):

This is using dojo.

Add the follwing in the head tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatequantity(input, id)
    dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "updatequantity.php",
            content: {
                  id: id,
                  quantity: input.value
            },
            load: function(result) {
                  result //this variable will hold the quantity
            }
    });
</script>
```

On the server: updatequantity.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
//some sql query like "update cart_items set quantity=".$quantity." where id=".$id.";"
echo $quantity;
```

This solution is very hacked together and venerable to many attacks such as sql injection and savy javascripters.